# Does installation occur during runtime, or during compile time?

Tags: language-agnostic, optimization, installation, build-time

According to published books suitable for a Wikipedia reference:

Does installation occur during runtime, or during compile time?

*'a "run-time error" is detected after or during the installation or copying of the program' --
[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Run_time_%28computing%29&oldid=352392693)*

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you don't understand the concepts involved. Let me clear it up for you.

- Compile time: the program is being translated from source code to machine code on some developer's computer
- Run time: the program is being executed on your machine
- Installation: The file(s) containing the machine code and resources for the program are being copied from some medium onto an executable place on your machine.

The three are quite unrelated.

Comment: I happen to agree with you. But our opinions aren't "verifiable" enough to use as a Wikipedia reference.

Comment: @David: Why do you need a Wikipedia reference? Unless I'm misunderstanding your question, you don't need a book or something to back you up on something as simple as this.

Comment: I am flattered that you think I am right and Wikipedia (as quoted above) is wrong.
Alas, those stubborn Wikipedians apparently refuse to immediately bow down to your obviously superior intellect.
I find it amusing to humor them in their little game of finding "verifiable references" for Wikipedia articles, and I thought you might also enjoy this game.
Also, I was kind of hoping that I would learn from such reference(s) some tips on improving installation, which often seems unnecessarily tedious, complex, and time-consuming.

Answer (score 2):

During [deployment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_deployment), which is neither run-time, nor compile time.

Deployment is generally considered as a separate phase of the [software development life cycle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_development_process) (SDLC).  THE SDLC includes the following phases, which are much broader than simply 'running' or 'compiling' software:

- Requirements
- Specification
- Architecture
- Design
- Implementation
- Testing
- Deployment
- Maintenance

**UPDATE**:  I didn't realize you want something Wikipedia citable.  [How does this book chapter look](http://books.google.com/books?id=2WIgTGnUaWsC&pg=PA73&dq=waterfall+deployment&cd=9#v=onepage&q=waterfall%20deployment&f=false)?

Comment: I suspect you are right. I like the term "deployment". And I appreciate the references you have given. Alas, they aren't really suitable for a Wikipedia reference -- they don't even mention the word "run" or "runtime", much less specifically say that runtime does not include deployment.

Comment: The book "Skills for managing rapidly changing IT projects" looks suitable for Wikipedia reference -- if it were relevant.
It clearly states that installation happens during deployment.
But I don't see any clear statement that run-time does *not* occur during deployment.
During which phase of a software's life does the user run the program?
Is that ever clearly stated in this book?

Answer (score 1):

"Installation" is an ill-defined term in this context.

In some older systems, "installation" could refer to the loading of an executable program into the systems memory in preparation to run. It's very unlikely that's what is being talked about here, but if so, that's a run-time operation.

Ordinarily people mean "positioned into the operating system such that the application (as opposed to just a program) will run correctly whenever a user calls on it. In this case, it happens after compile time (of course) and before run-time. Just when is up to system management.

Comment: Yes, when I say "compile-time", "installation time", and "run-time", I mean the ordinary non-overlapping times that you mention.
Have you ever seen that explicitly written down, where I can cite it, or is this bit of common knowledge something that has been passed down orally from our Great Lady?

Answer (score 0):

Well... compilation is a separate operation from installation, but to say that installation is "runtime" is a bit facetious, as the installation routine is usually separate from the application itself. So really, neither.